# Mathematica requires activation key for a Raspbian (jessie) session on Qemu

Tags: raspbian, qemu, wolfram-engine

First off, sorry if this is not the most suitable forum to post this question.

I downloaded a Raspbian "jessie" image to run on Linux with qemu. I'm chiefly interested in Mathematica and raspbian-jessie comes with one. The image loads OK and everything seems to be fine but Mathematica asks for an activation key when it should work out of the box (exactly as raspbian-wheezy's bundled Mathematica copy does). Someone suggested me to try:

```
sudo usermod -a -G video pi
```

and restart X, what I did, but it didn't work. The activation key input windows insists in popping up. 'pi' is the username of the Raspbian's session (which I confirmed by running 'whoami')

What should I try? Any suggestions?

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04-64 bit and the image 2017-04-10-raspbian-jessie.img

PS: Before I'm misunderstood (as I've recently been) I must say that I'm *not* trying to crack Mathematica, since I truly believe it's free when it comes bundled with Raspbian.

Comment: Perhaps it asks for an activation key because you are breaching the terms of use.  It is licensed for Pi use only.

Comment: @joan Yet Mathematica works out of the box and without any activation key requirements on a virtual (qemu) **raspbian-wheezy** session. Why does Mathematica work on wheezy but not on jessie? I don't think it's a matter of breaching some rule or terms of use. It's a software thing I reckon.

Comment: I would venture a guess as to they added stricter hardware checking in the version included with Raspbian Jessie.

Comment: @Jacobm001 Yep, that's always a possibility. Thanks for your insight.